# A Question on Random Variable Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose the p.d.f of the random variable X is as follows: 
$$
f(x) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  3x^2  & \mbox{for } 0< x <1 \\
  0 & \mbox{otherwise }
 \end{array}
\right.
$$
Also suppose that
$$ Y = 1 - X^2 $$
What is the p.d.f. of Y? 
I need a detailed answer and if you use the derivative in your solution please tell why you are doing that (The question is from the Probability and Statistics book).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variants of this question have been answered many times on this site. You may want to search for similar calculations.

Our strategy is to first find the *cumulative distribution function* $F_Y(y)$ of $Y$. This is the time-consuming part.

Then we differentiate $F_Y(y)$ to find the density function $f_Y(y)$ of $Y$.  The reason we differentiate is that the density function, for these continuous distributions, is the derivative of the cdf.

Recall that $F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)$.  Since (with probability $1$) $X$ is between $0$ and $1$, $1-X^2$ ranges between $1$ and $0$. We have
$$\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr(1-X^2\le y)=\Pr(X^2\ge 1-y)=\Pr(X\ge \sqrt{1-y}).$$
The last part holds because $X$ only takes on positive values. For random variables $X$ that can take on negative values, things get more complicated.

Now we need to find $\Pr(X \ge \sqrt{1-y})$. Recall that for any $a$ between $0$ and $1$, 
$$\Pr(X\le a) =\int_0^a 3x^2\,dx=a^3.$$
It follows that $\Pr(X \ge a)=1-a^3$. (We are using here the fact that the probability that $X$ is *exactly $a$ is $0$.)

We conclude that 
$$F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)=1-(\sqrt{1-y})^3=1-(1-y)^{3/2}$$
(for $0\lt y\lt 1$). For completeness, we note that $F_Y(y)=0$ if $y\le 0$, and $F_Y(y)=1$ if $y\ge 1$.

Finally, differentiate $F_Y(y)$ to get the density function. We find, using the Chain Rule, that
$$f_Y(y)=\frac{3}{2}(1-y)^{1/2}$$
(for $y$ between $0$ and $1$).